# Is there way to determine if a file has been executed or not in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to determine if a file has been executed or not. I've looked a bit into FileInfo's LastAccessTime but this doesn't seem to change when a file is executed. I've also looked into FileSystemWatcher but this also doesn't seem to offer a solution. Is there such a thing as a file execution listener or is there another way? If it helps, i'm looking to write a folder listener that renames an .avi file within it after it has been watched/executed.

Comment: Given your .avi case, is another program reading a file considered executing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a distinction between file being "executed" (e.g. a portable executable file, like an "exe") and a file being "accessed" (e.g. an AVI file that is "played" by another exe).

It sounds like you are looking in the right place and you will want the "LastAccessTime" but, be aware that resolution of the Access time is dependent on the file system...   On NTFS it's a full date/time, on FAT it's just the date (hence it won't change if it's already been accessed that day.)

Comment: Hi Damien, Thanks for your response. The file system is NTFS and I'm accessing the "LastAcessTime" by using:

DateTime example1 = File.GetLastAccessTime(@path);

The code is compiling but I'm confused by the results. The "LastAccessTime" doesn't change when I access the avi with my media player. In fact it still shows that exact same time and date as when the file was created. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Shane: You may have to force the system to re-read the file info, see my answer for details.

Comment: @egrunin: Thanks, I'll definitely look into that, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I tried Refreshing and it didn't seem to change anything. Any other thoughts?

Comment: A couple of other interesting points are discussed in this thread - http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35257064/how-do-i-access-a-file-wi.aspx

Specifically: LastAccessTime is disabled by default in vista and win 7, and under windows XP it's a "lazy" update (might take an hour for the OS to update the flag) and only gets updated for files that are accessed infrequently.  Perhaps you can use the "recently opened items" registry key?

Comment: It turns out that my NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate in my registry was set to 1, so I set it to 0 but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `LastAccessTime` might be what you want, since AVI files aren't "executed", only opened. I have, in the past, used it for exactly the purpose you describe, but not programmatically.

Just for the sake of completeness: Windows does not keep execution history, at least not publicly.

**Edited to add:**

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime.aspx), `LastAccessTime` is your best shot, however:

> Note   This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the operating system.

But this is followed a few lines later by:

> To get the latest value, call the Refresh method.

(This refers to `FileSystemInfo.Refresh`.)

It's all a little obtuse, if it doesn't work exactly as documented I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: I just looked at "Date accessed" using the explorer - it does not change when a file is opened. After looking at a few files it seems always to have the same value as "Date created" and therefore even predates "Date modified" for modified files.

Comment: By the way, Window 7 Enterprise 64 bit on a NTFS-formated disc if this should turn out to matter. Used Notepad and Notepad++ to open text files, Windows Photo Viewer for JPEG images, and 7Zip for some archives.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'm not too sure about finding out if a file has be run, but what might be a better approach would be to monitor the media player to determine when a video has finished playing.

Comment: Would there be a generic way to monitor *all* media players, or would he have to update his program every time there was a new media player capable of reading .avi files?